# Bad request invalid host when setting up logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am moving away from scheduled task collection in azure to logic apps.

I'm trying to do a SIMPLE logic app that calls a URL every 2 minutes

When it runs, it is receiving this error:

Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

1. Add a ReOccurrence -> this works fine, it is running every 2 minutes.
2. Add HTTP Action

   1. Set Method: Get
   2. Set URI: My url to run
   3. Set Headers: one header called VIA_METHOD
   4. Queries is EMPTY
   5. BODY is EMPTY
   6. Set Authentication is NONE
3. Save and run and his is the error I get:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "headers": {
        "Connection": "close",
        "Date": "Fri, 20 Sep 2019 02:42:07 GMT",
        "Server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
        "Content-Length": "334",
        "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=us-ascii"
    },
    "body": "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\"\"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\">\r\n<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>\r\n<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" Content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\"></HEAD>\r\n<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>\r\n<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>\r\n</BODY></HTML>\r\n"
}
```

Anyone know what it is failing? If I run the URL manually, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting the "header" and re-adding it. I'm wondering if there was some escape characters int the response for the header when I copied it over.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same "Invalid Host" error. In my case, I had a JWT token being used as the Authorization header. I had an extra CR/LF at the end of the token. I removed that extra CR/LF and the error no longer occurs.